# Best way to align table cells at an operator?

Tags: tables, formatting, datatool

I have some large upper triangular tables in csv form like this:

```
     ,           A,           B,         C
    D, $-10 \pm 2$, $52 \pm 40$, $9 \pm 3$
    C, $8 \pm 300$, $411 \pm 1$
    B,  $9 \pm 10$
```

The idea is to show all possible comparisons of A, B, C, and D. What is the nicest way to display a table like this? The first thing I want to do is center all the cells, aligning them at the plus-minus symbol. Other ideas as to how to make this table look nice would also be appreciated.

I have full control over the data itself, so if it makes sense to generate a totally different .csv, I can do that too.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The possible answers could strongly depend on whether you desire vertical lines between columns, horizontal lines between rows, etc.  Please let us know if there are particular constraints on the appearance.

Comment: I don't think I need column or line separators. The version you made below looks pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

The [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) package is primarily used for typesetting physical quantities with SI units, but can also be used for this purpose.

The package provides the `S` column type, which is used to typeset numbers with uncertainties in tables. By using the column specification

```
S[table-align-uncertainty]
```

will align the numbers at the plus-or-minus sign.

Comment: It's probably necessary (almost certainly highly desirable) to provide the option `separate-uncertainty=true` as well.

Comment: Can you show me the code you would write to load in the csv I provided and use these options? I'm having trouble getting it to align properly. Sorry, I'm fairly new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

If one did not need horizontal rules between rows of the data, then a grouped TABstack could suffice, in particular, an `\alignCenterstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
 & A & B& C\\
 \hline
 \Centerstack{D\cr C\cr B} & 
   {\ensurestackMath{
   \alignCenterstack{-10 \pm&2\cr 8\pm&300\cr 9\pm&10}}}
&
   {\ensurestackMath{
   \alignCenterstack{52 \pm&40\cr 411\pm&1\cr &}}}
&
   {\ensurestackMath{
   \alignCenterstack{9 \pm&3  \cr &       \cr &}}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, this answer does not address the equally challenging question of how to automate the process of getting csv data into the `tabular` format, but merely addresses the question of alignment on an operator.

Comment: This looks great. I'm having trouble figuring out how to automate this, though. I have some pretty large tables, so it's necessary. It might be outside the scope of this question, but if you could give me some tips, that would be great.

Comment: @WillAdler The packages `datatool` and `readarray` are two that I am aware of for digesting outside data.  That still does not make it trivial to use that data in an automated way, however.